# calculate percentage in high dimensional crosstab

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I have made a `crosstab` on 3 variables (`position`, `offer`, `group`). How can I calculate the percentage by the total of 1 variable `offer`, but not the margins (i.e. normalize by column)?

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.group, [df.position, df.offer], margins = True)
```

df

```
pid offer   position    group
1   accept  left        group1
1   accept  left        group1
1   accept  right       group2
1   reject  right       group2
1   reject  right       group1
2   reject  right       group1
2   reject  left        group2
2   accept  left        group3
3   accept  right       group3
3   reject  right       group1
3   reject  right       group2
```

my current crosstab:

```
 position         left                 right          All
 offer          accept   reject    accept   reject        
 group1         2         0           0       3       5
 group2         0         1           1       2       4
 group3         1         0           1       0       2
 All            3         1           2       5       11
```

expected outcome:

```
 position         left                 right
 offer          accept   reject    accept   reject       
 group1            1       0         0        1 
 group2            0       1         0.33     0.66  
 group3            1       0         1        0
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does `df` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another step, `groupby` the 0th level along columns and divide `c` by the `sum`.

```
c = pd.crosstab(df.group, [df.position, df.offer])
df = c / c.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
print(df)

position   left            right          
offer    accept reject    accept    reject
group                                     
group1      1.0    0.0  0.000000  1.000000
group2      0.0    1.0  0.333333  0.666667
group3      1.0    0.0  1.000000  0.000000
```

---

If you're as much of a perfectionist as I am, you might want the whole numbers as integers, you can do that like this:

```
df = c.div(c.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()).astype(object)
print(df)

position   left            right          
offer    accept reject    accept    reject
group                                     
group1        1      0         0         1
group2        0      1  0.333333  0.666667
group3        1      0         1         0
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED, how can I groupby mutilple levels? `groupby([level=0, level=1], axis=1) ` seems not work. Thanks!

Comment: @Kay `groupby(level=[0, 1], axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
In [4013]: dfa = df.groupby(['group', 'position', 'offer']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

In [4014]: dfa.div(dfa.sum(axis=1), axis=0).unstack()
Out[4014]:
offer    accept           reject
position   left     right   left     right
group
group1      1.0  0.000000    0.0  1.000000
group2      0.0  0.333333    1.0  0.666667
group3      1.0  1.000000    0.0  0.000000
```

---

You could also have `dfa` from `pivot_table` as well.

```
df.pivot_table(index=['group', 'position'], columns='offer', aggfunc=len)['pid']
```